# How to define static JNI class members in Gforth for Android?

Tags: android, forth, gforth

Gforth for Android has a Unix/jni-helper.fs file which defines the `getclip?` word which reads text from the clipboard. I want to implement `putclip` which puts text on the Android clipboard. For that I need to access the static ClipData::newPlainText() member. How do I define static JNI members in Gforth's object system?

Comment: have you tried http://www.forth-ev.de/wiki/doku.php/en:projects:gforth-android:start#jni_interface ?

Comment: I saw the page, but I somehow missed the jni-static: word. Thanks

Comment: @nsg: You could post a (comprehensive) answer - answering your own question is encouraged (there is even [a badge for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), *Self-Learner*). It would be interesting to see some actual Forth source code.